# Is there any 3rd party tool to mirror/flip the screen?

Tags: mirroring

I would like to use a mirror with my screen, is there anyway that the screen can be completely flipped horizontally? Of course I know there are ways to flip text and movies. Best would be an open-source or at least free as in beer app. Target Os could be windows or linux.

I did some googling and didn't find anything that flips the whole screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xrandr -o inverted` or `xrandr -x` or `xrandr -y` (depending on how your mirror is configured)

Return to normal with:

`xrandr -o normal`

Comment: Thanks for the linux answer, is there any solution for windows?